# Encrypt Kali and Ubuntu in Dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, encryption, kali

I have a fairly large hard disk and am trying to dual boot Kali Linux and Ubuntu with encryption. My problem is that depending on which OS I created as the last one, I can only boot the last one and the other OS is no longer recognized by GRUB due to the encryption.

I attempted to install one encrypted os, then the other, and then insert parts of the GRUB configuration into the other, but without success.

Is it possible to dual boot Kali and Ubuntu while they are encrypted with different passphrases?

Comment: Yes, but you've given no specifics as to what type of encryption you've tried. If you're talking about full disk encryption you'll have issues, if you're talking partition encryption you're good to go... This box isn't encrypted, but the box besides me is dual boot with two encrypted Ubuntu releases (*bionic* and *impish*).  You also didn't provide release details (if I boot current ISOs of Ubuntu, I need to add packages first to read the encryption on my system as its longer default for Ubuntu; Kali is off-topic here though).

Comment: If you've both installed, it should be easy to make `grub` boot the other, or at least `chainloader` to it...

Comment: I mean partition  encryption and i tried the standart encryption of ubuntu and kali. I think it is LUKS

Comment: Yes it is, given the encryption you'll need to do a fair amount of the setup yourself, as once an OS is encrypted, the other OS won't be able to read what's there and so you'll have to manually install around it. Modern releases of Ubuntu use full disk encryption (you won't be able to use) by default; but my own system (installed by an older release) has partition encryption; what you need.. I've re-installed it a few times; boot the *live* media, add packages (if not on ISO) then perform install... but your question is missing specifics so adjust for your *unstated* release/installer/ISO etc

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I installed one os with grub and then the other os with grub too. So now I have grubs on the system and I copied the one grub that isn’t used into the other and it booted just fine. The only thing I noticed, you have to have both grub on the drive else it won’t start.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1188104)